# Angular - merge https request results into the same array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working with two https requests from two different endpoints and I use forkJoin to get the two results merged. What I'm struggling with is to pass data from "info" to the corresponding team in "standings" as "info" contains more detailed information of each football team.

My service:

```
  espStandings() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Leagueinfo>('http://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/v2/sports/soccer/esp.1/standings?desc');
  }
  espInfo() {
    return this.httpClient.get<Teaminfo>('https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/soccer/esp.1/teams');
  }
  public getEsp() {
    return forkJoin(this.espStandings(), this.espInfo()).pipe(map(([standings, info]) => {
      return { standings, info };
    }));
  }
```

Standings returns an array with all the teams like this (this is the first team in the entries array):

```
entries: Array(20)
0:
note: {color: "#81D6AC", description: "Champions League", rank: 1}
stats: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
team: {id: "3747", uid: "s:600~t:3747", location: "Granada", name: "Granada", abbreviation: "GCF", …}
```

What I want is to add another object called "record" to each team in "entries" with data from "info".

The "record" object from the "info" result look like this:

```
record:
items: Array(1)
0:
stats: (22) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

So the final output for each team would be:

```
entries: Array(20)
0:
note: {color: "#81D6AC", description: "Champions League", rank: 1}
stats: (10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
team: {id: "3747", uid: "s:600~t:3747", location: "Granada", name: "Granada", abbreviation: "GCF", …}
record: {items: Array(1)}
```

JSON example for standings:

```
{
    "uid": "s:600~l:740",
    "id": "15",
    "name": "Spanish Primera División",
    "abbreviation": "La Liga",
    "children": [
        {
            "uid": "s:600~l:740~g:1",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "2019-20 LaLiga",
            "abbreviation": "2019-2020",
            "standings": {
                "id": "0",
                "name": "overall",
                "displayName": "Overall Standings",
                "links": [
                    {
                        "language": "en",
                        "rel": [
                            "standings",
                            "desktop"
                        ],
                        "href": "http://www.espn.com/spanish-primera-division/15/table",
                        "text": "Table",
                        "shortText": "Table",
                        "isExternal": false,
                        "isPremium": false
                    }
                ],
                "season": 2019,
                "seasonType": 1,
                "entries": [
                    {
                        "team": {
                            "id": "3747",
                            "uid": "s:600~t:3747",
                            "location": "Granada",
                            "name": "Granada",
                            "abbreviation": "GCF",
                            "displayName": "Granada",
                            "shortDisplayName": "Granada",
                            "isActive": true,
                            "logos": [
                                {
                                    "href": "https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/soccer/500/3747.png",
                                    "width": 500,
                                    "height": 500,
                                    "alt": "",
                                    "rel": [
                                        "full",
                                        "default"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "links": [
                                {
                                    "language": "en",
                                    "rel": [
                                        "clubhouse",
                                        "desktop",
                                        "team"
                                    ],
                                    "href": "http://www.espn.com/football/club/_/id/3747/granada",
                                    "text": "Clubhouse",
                                    "shortText": "Clubhouse",
                                    "isExternal": false,
                                    "isPremium": false
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "note": {
                            "color": "#81D6AC",
                            "description": "Champions League",
                            "rank": 1
                        },
                        "stats": [
                            {
                            }
                        ]
```

JSON example for info:

```
{
    "sports": [
        {
            "id": "600",
            "uid": "s:600",
            "name": "Football",
            "slug": "soccer",
            "leagues": [
                {
                    "id": "740",
                    "uid": "s:600~l:740",
                    "name": "Spanish Primera División",
                    "abbreviation": "La Liga",
                    "shortName": "La Liga",
                    "slug": "spanish-primera-division",
                    "teams": [
                        {
                            "team": {
                                "id": "96",
                                "uid": "s:600~t:96",
                                "slug": "alaves",
                                "location": "Alavés",
                                "name": "Alavés",
                                "abbreviation": "ALV",
                                "displayName": "Alavés",
                                "shortDisplayName": "Alavés",
                                "color": "0000ff",
                                "alternateColor": "C8142F",
                                "isActive": true,
                                "isAllStar": false,
                                "logos": [
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/soccer/500/96.png",
                                        "width": 500,
                                        "height": 500,
                                        "alt": "",
                                        "rel": [
                                            "full",
                                            "default"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "href": "https://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/soccer/500-dark/96.png",
                                        "width": 500,
                                        "height": 500,
                                        "alt": "",
                                        "rel": [
                                            "full",
                                            "dark"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ],
                                "record": {
                                    "items": [
                                        {
                                            "summary": "1-2-2",
                                            "stats": []
                                        }
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Did you try using `map` once you have response? Or simplest way could even be to do it brute force way once you have both responses.

Comment: How can you determine which entry from `info` belongs to which entry from `standings`? Could you add the structure of `info` and `standings` as correct json.

Comment: @fridoo both info and standings contains a team id or name that can be used in determining which entry that belongs to standings. I've updated the question with a JSON example response for each request.

Comment: find the common key from both array and  using .filter() or .find() method  fetch the object.